# Merge word segments that are overlapping or contained within other segments python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, opencv, wordsegment

I am working on a project that involves word segmentation in images containing handwritten text. I am using the [scale space technique for word segmentation](https://github.com/doktoroblivion/WordSegmentation) for this.

One problem is the overlapping segments as shown in the picture:

[image]

I want to merge any 2 overlapping segments (or segment contained within other segment) into one (for all such segments in a line).

Below is the code which I tried:

```
def segment_cleaner(seg,dist = 20):
    
    seg : segments as list of list of tuples in the form [[(x1,y1),(x1+w,y1+h)],[(x2,y2),(x2+w,y2+h)],...]
    dist : represents the minimum distance between 2 segments, if the dist is less then merge the 2 segments
    
    if len(seg) ==2:
        return seg
    
    else:
        
        cleaned_seg = []
        #arrange segments from left to right
        sorteg_seg = sorted(seg, key=lambda x: x[0])

        #loop through segments, if there is overlapp, one segment is contained inside other or two segements 
        #are less than the dist argument apart, combine them together
        x_pointer = 0
        for i in range(len(sorteg_seg)-1):
            i_th_seg = sorteg_seg[i]
            i_plus1th_seg = sorteg_seg[i+1]

            #condition for containment 
            contained = i_th_seg[0][0] < i_plus1th_seg[0][0] and i_th_seg[0][1] < i_plus1th_seg[0][1] and i_th_seg[1][0] > i_plus1th_seg[1][0] and i_th_seg[1][1] > i_plus1th_seg[1][1]

            if contained:
                #ignore the smaller segement
                print('remove contained rect.')
                if i_th_seg[1][0]>x_pointer:
                    cleaned_seg.append(i_th_seg)
                    x_pointer = i_th_seg[1][0]

            elif i_plus1th_seg[0][0] - i_th_seg[1][0] <= dist:
                print('merge segements')
                x_min = min(i_th_seg[0][0],i_plus1th_seg[0][0])
                y_min = min(i_th_seg[0][1],i_plus1th_seg[0][1])
                x_max = max(i_th_seg[1][0],i_plus1th_seg[1][0])
                y_max = max(i_th_seg[1][1],i_plus1th_seg[1][1])

                append_seg = [(x_min,y_min),(x_max,y_max)]
                if x_max > x_pointer:
                    cleaned_seg.append(append_seg)
                    x_pointer = x_max

            else:
                if i_th_seg[1][0]>x_pointer:
                    cleaned_seg.append(i_th_seg)
                if i_plus1th_seg[1][0]>x_pointer and i ==len(sorteg_seg)-2 :
                    cleaned_seg.append(i_plus1th_seg)

        return cleaned_seg
```

It does not work as desired, since the segments are dynamically updated as we loop through the list of segments. Appreciate any help on this.

segments_scp = [[(75, 0), (189, 52)], [(126, 0), (243, 61)], [(347, 0), (419, 50)], [(419, 0), (507, 50)], [(507, 13), (668, 70)]]

segment_cleaner(segments_scp)

output : [[(75, 0), (243, 61)], [(347, 0), (507, 50)], [(419, 0), (668, 70)]]

desired output : [[(75, 0), (243, 61)], [(347, 0), (668, 70)]]

Comment: If you plot the input data, then you'll see there are 5 bounding boxes which form 3 groups in total. So your desired (merged) output with 2 bounding boxes does not really make sense.

Comment: @Harry Thanks for pointing it out. please consider the updated the inputs and output